# Site graduated! New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

The [Twitter profile](https://twitter.com/stacknetworkeng) and the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=networkengineering.stackexchange.com) also got a facelift. Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Woop Woop, looks good.  Thanks for all your work.

Comment: Design looks great.  The iconic router used as the "O" in networking fits, the console font for the nav banner is a good choice, and the nav background image with the network topology map is on point.  Good job to whoever did it!

Comment: Thanks @RonRoyston! The community has been a great help in the design.

Comment: Why the cool background on Meta, but not on the Main?  I definitely like the terminal/mono-spaced font.